# forge laravel custom ssl setup

Tags: laravel, ssl, forge

I'd like to install a custom ssl certificate provided by comodo on a forge (forge.laravel.com) managed digitalocean server. From comodo I've got a .csr, .crt and .ca-bundle files for installation. According to forge I need to enter the private key and the certificate itself.
But I'm not sure about which values to insert into the fields.
I've got the following:

```
.ca-bundle
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

.csr
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Certificate Signing Request(CSR)
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Your Private Server Key

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've tried to enter the value from .crt as certificate and the private key from the .csr file.

But it doesn't seem to work?
Did I do it correctly? Do I need to restart the server - I guess not, as I didn't found any information in the docs.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

including the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" lines.

The private key is

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

also with "---" lines.

The rest of the data is for your information only and is not necessary for the server/load balancer configuration.

Comment: thank you I've tried it with your suggestion.
Is it possible that this will take a while to see the effect? Previously I've used a Let's encrypt certificate and although I've activated the new one - I see the old certificate

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did it, but nginx couldn't start due to following error message:
SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch